# Generic type in Python which falls back depending on which argument was passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, mypy

I have a function like:

```
def foo(a, b = None): ...
```

I would like the function to be generic so that it returns the same type as b if b is supplied, otherwise the type of a. So

```
foo(a=123, b="abc") # -> str
foo(a=123) # -> int
```

---

I've been trying to use overloads to achieve this but have errors:

```
from typing import Hashable, overload, Optional, TypeVar, Generic, Protocol
from os import PathLike
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

AnyPath = PathLike[str] | str
TPkgUID = TypeVar("TPkgUID", bound = Hashable)

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class RepoInfo(Generic[TPkgUID]):
    path: AnyPath = field(hash=False, repr=False)
    unique_identifier: TPkgUID = field(hash=True, repr=True)
    

@overload
def register_repo(path: AnyPath, unique_identifier: TPkgUID) -> RepoInfo[TPkgUID]: ...
@overload
def register_repo(path: TPkgUID, unique_identifier: Optional[TPkgUID] = None) -> RepoInfo[TPkgUID]: ...

def register_repo(
    path: AnyPath , unique_identifier: Optional[TPkgUID] = None
) -> RepoInfo[TPkgUID]:
    if unique_identifier is None:
        assert isinstance(path, Hashable)
        unique_identifier = path
    return RepoInfo(path, unique_identifier) #unique_identifier falls back to path as long as path is hashable
```

Comment: Why do you want function overloading in the first place? IMO the pythonic approach would be to write the function to check for the type that was passed, then branch into the necessary code to handle it.

Comment: @sarema that's what their function does, the issue is how to type annotate it

Answer (score 1):

Removing the types from the signature and only keeping the overloads seems to work.

```
from typing import Hashable, overload, Optional, TypeVar, Generic, Protocol
from os import PathLike
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

AnyPath = PathLike[str] | str
TPkgUID = TypeVar("TPkgUID", bound = Hashable)

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class RepoInfo(Generic[TPkgUID]):
    path: AnyPath = field(hash=False, repr=False)
    unique_identifier: TPkgUID = field(hash=True, repr=True)
    

@overload
def register_repo(path: AnyPath, unique_identifier: TPkgUID) -> RepoInfo[TPkgUID]: ...
@overload
def register_repo(path: TPkgUID, unique_identifier: None = None) -> RepoInfo[TPkgUID]: ...

def register_repo(
    path , unique_identifier = None
) -> RepoInfo:
    if unique_identifier is None:
        if isinstance(path, Hashable):
            unique_identifier = path
    return RepoInfo(path, unique_identifier) #unique_identifier falls back to path as long as path is hashable

# e.g.
from pathlib import Path
reveal_type(register_repo("foo", 2))   # RepoInfo[int] (type(b))
reveal_type(register_repo("foo"))      # RepoInfo[str] (falls back to a)
reveal_type(register_repo(Path(), {})) # Error: dict not hashable
```

`unique_identifier: None = None` or `unique_identifier: TPkgUID = None` are equivalent because this will only be matched on non-hashable and missing args. `unique_identifier: Any = None` is a mistake though.

Comment: that simply means you're not type-checking your implementation, in which case you're probably better off `# type: ignore`-ing the specific line and error that doesn't work

Comment: @joel Well I'm type checking invocations of the function (see the examples at the bottom) - if mypy finds none of the overloads matches then it raises an error, like with the first one where even though `unique_identifier` is `Any` in the implementation, a non-hashable dict is rejected since both overloads require `unique_identifier` to be either hashable or missing. There is a risk I guess that the implementation signature is wider than the overloads - meaning I can define an overload that's too wide but I don't think I've done that here, and that's not a concern for type-checking time